# Comma in "for all"-sentences, after "In most cases"

Tags: commas

1. Should there be a comma in "for all"-sentences? For example, is the comma in the following sentence correct?

> For all b ∈ B**,** there is an a ∈ A such that f(a) = b.

2. Suppose that one wants to start a sentence with "In most cases". Should there be a comma after that? For example, is the comma in the following sentence correct?

> In most cases**,** (a + b)² = a² + b² is false.

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned examples are correct. As "For all b ∈ B" and "In most cases" are the introductory clauses so they must have comma. For more explanation refer this [website](https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/comma/8/comma-after-introductory-clauses/).